# Can two Linux partitions use the same swap space?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, swap

I have Ubuntu 10.04 and Windows 7 installed on my machine, due to some reasons I need to install one more copy of Ubuntu.. Is it possible that the new Ubuntu uses the same swap space used by previous one?

Answer (score 14):

Yes you can use the same swap partition, unless you use hibernate to swap on either of those. If you don't use [hibernate](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq), you're fine.

Comment: And even if you hibernate, the hibernated distro should force the bootloader to load it.

Comment: Nice catch Ignacio.